# i want to read this log files, in putty - ssh

Tags: unix, ssh, putty

I want to read this log files, I'm new to putty.
What commands should I give? Why this files are in different color?

[image: Putty Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `cat` or `less` command to read the log files, for example:

```bash
cat /var/log/pemig.log

# or
less /var/log/pemig.log
```

For more information about `cat` and `less`, you could read the manual:

```
man cat
man less
```

As for the colors, it's not Putty that does the coloring, it's `dircolors`. You could run the `dircolors -p` command, it will tell you what color maps to each known file type.

Comment: Thank you , able to open the logs, its so helpful.

Comment: How should i gain Permission to directory's  , I'm getting  "Permission denied"

Comment: As for `/var/log` directory, it needs `root` permission, you could temporarily gain the permission by using `sudo`, for example `sudo cat /var/log/pemig.log`